# Criar 2 arquivos zipados com arquivos de uma pasta

Tags: python, arquivo-zip

Estou tentando criar um código que lê um diretório com arquivos pdf e cria 2 arquivos zipados contendo esses pdf, no meu código, só consegui jogar todos pdf em um único arquivo zipado, minha dúvida é como criar os dois.

Código:

```
class zipar_pdf:
    
    def __init__(self, diretorio, nome):
        self.diretorio = diretorio
        self.nome = nome        

    def zipar(self):        
        #Criando arquivo zip com os pdf          
        with zipfile.ZipFile(self.nome, "w") as oZip:            
            print('Buscando arquivos...\n')            
            for caminho, _ , arquivos in os.walk(self.diretorio):
                print(f'Compactando arquivos em {self.nome}...\n')
                for arquivo in arquivos:
                    caminhoCompleto = os.path.join(caminho, arquivo)                    
                    if arquivo.startswith("test"):                        
                        oZip.write(caminhoCompleto, basename(caminhoCompleto))
        
PDF = zipar_pdf(r'exemplo_diretorio', 'arquivos.zip')
PDF.zipar()
```

No diretório tem 6 pdf, com o nome test1.pdf, até test6.pdf, é possível colocar até o test3 em um arquivo zipado e depois o resto em outro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma alternativa é usar [`pathlib.Path.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) passando um *pattern* correspondente aos nomes dos arquivos que você quer, e adicionar somente estes arquivos no zip. Só que aí você vai precisar de um nome diferente para cada arquivo zip.

Outro ponto é que não sei se precisa mesmo ter uma classe para isso, acho "exagero" demais. Ficaria assim:

```
from pathlib import Path
import zipfile

diretorio = 'exemplo_diretorio'
zip_config = { # mapeia o nome do arquivo zip com os arquivos que ele terá
    'arquivos1.zip': 'teste[1-3].pdf', # de 1 a 3
    'arquivos2.zip': 'teste[4-6].pdf' # de 4 a 6
}

p = Path(diretorio)
for zip_name, file_pattern in zip_config.items():
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_name, "w") as oZip:
        for f in p.glob(file_pattern):
            oZip.write(f, f.name)
```

---

No máximo, eu faria uma função que recebe o diretório e as configurações dos arquivos zip:

```
def zipar(diretorio, zip_config):
    p = Path(diretorio)
    for zip_name, file_pattern in zip_config.items():
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_name, "w") as oZip:
            for f in p.glob(file_pattern):
                oZip.write(f, f.name)

zipar('exemplo_diretorio', { 'arquivos1.zip': 'teste[1-3].pdf', 'arquivos2.zip': 'teste[4-6].pdf' })
```

Assim você pode reaproveitar a lógica, bastando mudar os parâmetros informados (por exemplo, se quiser um único zip com todos os arquivos, bastaria passar `{ 'tudo.zip': '*.pdf' }`).

---

Mas se quer muito usar uma classe (que como já disse, acho meio "exagero"/desnecessário para este caso), ficaria algo assim:

```
class ZiparPdf:
    def __init__(self, diretorio, zip_config):
        self.diretorio = diretorio
        self.zip_config = zip_config

    def zipar(self):
        p = Path(self.diretorio)
        for zip_name, file_pattern in self.zip_config.items():
            with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_name, "w") as oZip:
                for f in p.glob(file_pattern):
                    oZip.write(f, f.name)

z = ZiparPdf('exemplo_diretorio', { 'arquivos1.zip': 'teste[1-3].pdf', 'arquivos2.zip': 'teste[4-6].pdf' })
z.zipar()
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda!
Sobre usar classes, o motivo é que estou aprendendo sobre esse assunto e pensei em aplicar, sou novo na área de programação, fiz uma outra versão apenas com uma função que estava dando o mesmo resultado

Comment: @VitorXavier Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. Não esqueça que [**vc também pode votar**](/help/privileges/vote-up) na resposta, caso tenha achado útil.

Comment: Uma pergunta, nessa função, está pegando os arquivos test.pdf pelo numero que vem acompanhado na frente dele, tem alguma função que colocaria os arquivos dentro do .zip por quantidade e não pelo nome?

Comment: @VitorXavier Não conheço, provavelmente vc vai ter que contar manualmente (talvez usar um contador no loop, por exemplo). Ou vc pega a lista de todos os arquivos e aí vai iterando por partes. Ex: `arquivos = list(Path(diretorio).glob('*.pdf'))` para ter uma lista com todos os pdf's, e depois pega `arquivos[0:10]` para os 10 primeiros (do zero ao 9), depois `arquivos[10:20]` para pegar do décimo até o décimo nono, etc